# How can I make a menu link visible only to admins (without plugins)?

Tags: menus, pages, admin

I use a menu on top of my wordpress which shows 3 links.

1. Main page
2. Custom Page
3. Custom Page

Can I add a 4th link to my menu which is visible and accessible to admins only (without plugins)? This 4th page would also be a custom page I make. How would I go about setting this up, or does anyone have somewhere to start?

Comment: Saying without plugins is akin to saying without code.

Comment: How is your menu output in your theme, is it a [Navigation Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus), or [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages), or?

Comment: @Wyck Maybe I used bad wording, but basically I don't want to use someone elses code added as a plugin. I want to edit the php pages myself if that makes sense. The information is sensitive and I don't like blindly trusting plugins which I don't really know about.

Comment: @Milo I'm not sure what you mean. Here's what loads the menu on my header.php: `echo theme_get_menu(array('source' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_source'), 'depth' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_depth'), 'menu' => 'primary-menu', 'class' => 'fmls-hmenu'));` Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can show or hide something based on a user's role with the [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function. For the Administrator role you would check if `current_user_can( 'administrator' )`.

Here's a quick and dirty example of hiding a nav menu item by first checking if the title matches a particular page, and then checking if the current user is *not* an administrator, via the `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter. If both conditions are satisfied, the menu item is removed via php's [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items ){
    foreach( $items as $key => $item ){
        if( 'Private page' == $item->title && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){
            unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects' );
```

Comment: Please remember, the title of the page is case-sensitive.